# How to charge percentage of transaction cost?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, gas, gas-limit

Example:

```
uint public createPostCost = 0.0003 ether;

function createPost(bytes32 _post) 
    public payable {
        require(msg.value >= createPostCost);
        Post memory newPost;
        newPost.post = _post;
    }
```

Within a discussion forum dapp, the current implementation charges users a set fee per post created. I would like the charge to be dynamic, say 10% of the gas cost of the transaction. Is this possible to implement in the contract? Or is this something for front-end web3 to handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can let the charge be a function of the gas of the transaction. You would do something like this:

`uint256 charge = gasleft() / 10;`

This is sensitive and you should know that `gasleft()` returns the *amount of gas available at that point in the execution*. Therefore, if you call `gasleft()` at the beginning of a function, the number will be higher than at the end of the function.

Additionally, someone may send a lot of unnecessary gas, so they could end up paying a lot.

My opinion is that it is best to handle this on the front-end.

#### Edit

If you are trying to take into account the `gasPrice`, you can use `tx.gasprice`. See [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) for more information.

Comment: Psst, `msg.gas` has been removed and replaced by `gasleft` as per https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties

Comment: Ah that makes sense. If I made a require to check the msg.value >= 10% of tx.gasprice, would that work? Would there be discrepancies between generating the web3 function call price + value and the contract value?

Comment: I have tried to implement this and can't get it to work. Would you perhaps know of an implementation?